# loading screen with "continue reading" text

Tags: php, wordpress

When I go to the page, the first screen for like 1 second, while the page is loading, is a screen with this 'continue reading' text

maybe someone had the same bug or maybe you knew where in code it could go wrong

the website is based on wordpress

thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so strange, the first thing that come in my mind is: do a search on your source file in theme and plugin folder for the term "Continue reading", seems to be an undisclosed tag that cause this issue. I've this suspect because of this output **">**

Comment: So  the problem was in meta description tag, it generates automatically and sometimes there are links inside text, so I just changed  

    `<meta property="og:description" content="<?= get_the_excerpt() ?>">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="<?= get_the_excerpt() ?>">`

to 

    `<meta property="og:description" content="<?= strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()) ?>">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="<?= strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()) ?>">`